# Check whether the string contains special character in starting and ending

Tags: c#

I want to check whether a string starts or end with a special character.

```
string a = "%test1*";
string b ="%test2";
string c ="test3%";
string d = "te!st";

bool aResult = ContainsSpecialChars(a);
bool bResult = ContainsSpecialChars(b);
bool cResult = ContainsSpecialChars(c);
bool dResult = ContainsSpecialChars(d);
```

In the example above, the first three strings start or end  with a special character. The d string contains the special character in between. If I use the following function it will return true for all these examples.

```
 private bool ContainsSpecialChars(string value)
        {
            var list = new[] { "~", "`", "<", ">", "!", "?", ";", ":", "|", "{", "}", "[", "]", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "*", "(", ")", "+", "=", "\"" };
            return list.Any(value.Contains);
        }
```

Now I want to check for the presence of a special character at the beginning or the end of a string, nowhere else.

Comment: Can you not use `value.StartsWith()` ?

Answer (score 2):

Just needs a slight tweak:

```
return list.Any(e => value.StartsWith(e) || value.EndsWith(e));
```

FWIW I wouldn't call the method "ContainsSpecial.." I'd call it "StartsOrEndsWithSpecial..."

By the way, if you're using core you might consider that it looks neater to not have a list but just use a string because a string can be treated like an IEnumerable of char, and the Starts/EndsWith methods accept a char (in .NET Core):

```
var chars = "~`<>!?;:|{}[]@#$%^*()+=\"";

return chars.Any(c => value.StartsWith(c) || value.EndsWith(c));
```

This way is limited to single chars; your first way could conceptually have "special chars" be a sequence of chars, but because all the strings in your first list were only a length of 1 it looks like your intent was to have it be single characters only. If you're using .net framework you could still leverage this with something like:

```
var list = "~ ` < > ! ? ; : | { } [ ] @ # $ % ^ * ( ) + = \" ".Split();
```

If you're doing this a lot (using this helper method on millions of strings) I would perhaps make this/your `list` a class level variable so you're not creating it all the time

---

You can also do this in a way that avoids LINQ:

```
var chars = "~`<>!?;:|{}[]@#$%^*()+=\"";

return chars.IndexOf(value[0]) > -1 || chars.IndexOf(value[value.Length-1]) > -1;
```

I don't find it quite as readable, but the nuts and bolts of it are the same - this way asks "for these start/end characters are either of them in this list of chars" and the other way asks "for this list of chars are any of them present at the start/end of this string"; different ends of the same stick, and the indexof route is likely a micro optimization

Answer (score 0):

If testing if the character is not letter or digit or space for example is sufficient you can write:

```
private bool ContainsSpecialChars(string value)
{
  if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ) return false;
  return !value[0].IsLetterOreDigit() && !value[0].IsSpace()
      && !value[value.Length - 1].IsLetterOreDigit() && !value[value.Length - 1].IsSpace();
}
```

You can adapt to what you want even use the array in your code:

```
using System.Linq;

private char[] SpecialChars = new char[] { '~', '`', '<', '>', '!', '?', ';', ':', '|', '{', '}', '[', ']', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '*', '(', ')', '+', '=', '\'' };

private bool ContainsSpecialChars(string value)
{
  if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ) return false;
  return SpecialChars.Contains(value.First()) || SpecialChars.Contains(value.Last());
}
```

We put the array outside the method as a member of the class to optimize memory and speed.

`First()` and `Last()` are Linq extension methods that do the same thing as `value[0]` and `value[value.Length - 1]` that are faster... but using indexer can cause out of bound exception in case of typing error.

And as @CaiusJard wrote, you should name the method `StartsOrEndsWithSpecialChar`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are going to check if a character is present in a set many times, use an efficient type of collection for lookups. In this case, `HashSet<char>`.

And now simply check the first and last character (using C# new indexer syntax):

```
var specialCharacters = new HashSet<char>(new[] { .... });

public static bool StartsOrEndsWithSpecialCharacter(
    this string s, 
    HashSet<char> specialCharacters)
{
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ||
           specialCharacters.Contains(s[0]) ||
           specialCharacters.Contains(s[^1]);
}
```

You have a list of strings you need to check? Use linq:

```
var stringsINeedToCheck = //some IEnumerable<string>
var stringsThatStartOrEndWithSpecialCharacter =
    stringsINeedToCheck.Where(s =>  s.StartsOrEndsWithSpecialCharacter(
                                        specialCharacters));
```